# RegEx in Oracle SQL, positive look ahead

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a string and I'd like to capture everything before "\Close_Out":

string:  \fileshare\R and G\123456\Close_Out\Warranty Letter.pdf

The only solution I have come up with uses positive  lookahead, this works when I test it on https://regex101.com/

```
(.*)(?=\\Close_Out)
```

But now I need to use it in an Oracle SQL statement :

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('\\fileshare\R and G\123456\Close_Out\Warranty Letter.pdf', '(.*)(?=\\Close_Out)') from dual
```

and it does not work since (I think) look ahead is not supported. Can someone assist with an alternative expression that will work in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If regular expressions isn't a *must*, then `substr` + `instr` does the job:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '\fileshare\R and G\123456\Close_Out\Warranty Letter.pdf' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 1, instr(col,'\Close_Out') - 1) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-------------------------
\fileshare\R and G\123456

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was over complicating things trying to use REGEX. Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completness this REGEXP provides the result *inclusive* the `\Close_Out`

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('\\fileshare\R and G\123456\Close_Out\Warranty Letter.pdf', '.*\\Close_Out') reg from dual;


REG                                 
------------------------------------
\\fileshare\R and G\123456\Close_Out
```

To get the string *before* it use a *subexpression* - a part enclosed in paretheses and reference it with the *subexpression* parameter = 1 (last parameter - see details in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099)).

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('\\fileshare\R and G\123456\Close_Out\Warranty Letter.pdf', '(.*)\\Close_Out', 1, 1, null, 1) reg from dual;


REG                       
--------------------------
\\fileshare\R and G\123456
```